# How to run a command in a bash program?

Tags: bash

I can run this command

```
./dropbox_uploader.sh upload /home/pi/abc.jpg abc.jpg
```

successfully in commandline and I'd like run it inside a bash program but I cant.

My script is:

```
picfiles=`ls /home/pi/Dropbox-Uploader/*jpg`
for i in $picfiles;do
path="/home/pi/Dropbox-Uploader/dropbox_uploader.sh"
eval $path 
upload "$i"
done
```

Comment: Please format your code. See [How do I format code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361)

Comment: You should also specify what error message (if any) you get while running the program.

Comment: Most likely you want to do `echo upload $i |  $path` if `upload` is an interactive command for `dropbox_uploader.sh`

Comment: BTW, what benefit do you get from putting `path` in a variable?

Comment: @Corion, ...albeit with more quotes. `echo "upload $i" | "$path"` or `"$path" <<<"upload $i"`  is going to behave more consistently without regard to the shell's current state (f/e, the current value of `IFS`). Of course, that assumes that the OP *does* want to send those on stdin, whereas the initial line showing they command they already run implies that they're feeding their arguments on the command line instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `$(...)` rather than backticks (`` `...` ``) unless you are on a particularly archaic version of `sh` that doesn't support `$()`.
- Don't parse `ls`
- I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do with your `eval` but it's not correct.

Here is a better script:

```
pic_directory="/home/pi/Dropbox-Uploader"
uploader_path="/home/pi/Dropbox-Uploader/dropbox_uploader.sh"
# Use globbing so the files aren't word-split incorrectly.
for pic in "$pic_directory"/*.jpg; do
    # ${var##glob} removes the longest match of `glob` from the front of `var`.
    "$uploader_path" upload "$pic" "${pic##*/}"
    # You could also use `basename` and command substitution:
    #"$uploader_path" upload "$pic" "$(basename "$pic")"
done
```

Comment: (Extending that "particularly archaic" note -- the 1992 POSIX.2 specification requires `$(...)`, and it existed in ksh well before that standard was published, so we're talking 1970s-era shells; if you could use `^` as a pipe character instead of `|`, then your shell is probably the relevant vintage).

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your script (you should not use ls for this need, be careful using find instead, do not define same variable in each loop, do not use useless eval instruction).

After some exchanges in comments, and taking care of good advice about [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29), this is a way to improve your script:

```
path="/home/pi/Dropbox-Uploader/dropbox_uploader.sh"
picFilesDir="/tmp/filesToFind"

while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
  "$path" upload "$file" "${file##*/}"
done < <( find "$picFilesDir" -type f -iname '*.jpg' -print0 )
```

You can read GNU/Bash online Manual about [Shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) if you want additional understanding.

Comment: By contrast, `for i in /home/pi/Dropbox-Uploader/*jpg; do` will work properly, and doesn't require `ls` at all.

Comment: Still buggy as amended to use `find`. See [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29), and try testing with a filename containing spaces, and [UsingFind](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) for an extensive discussion of what it takes to use `find` correctly/safely.

Comment: `find /home/pi/Dropbox-Uploader -type f -iname '*.jpg' -exec "$path" upload '{}' ';'` would work, by contrast; it's the `for i in $(...)` that's a source of pain and suffering, no matter if the `...` is `ls` or `find`.

Comment: ...similarly, `while IFS= read -r -d '' i; do "$path" upload "$i"; done < <(find /home/pi/Dropbox-Uploader -type f -iname '*.jpg' -print0)` is another alternative -- albeit a bash-only one -- that works properly regardless of filename contents (spaces, quotes, literal newlines, etc).

Comment: For an example of a devious filename, btw, consider `i=$'\n/etc/passwd\n/etc/shadow\n'; mkdir -p -- "$i" && touch -- "$i/hello.jpg"` (`$'\n'` is a way to write a newline literal in bash); you don't want your `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` getting uploaded to Dropbox, which will happen if you use line-oriented processing of a stream of filenames where that name is included.

Comment: I agree with you. I'll update my answer tomorrow (in a train atm for. 1k km).

Comment: Please note the command line: `upload /home/pi/abc.jpg abc.jpg`; it seems a further parameter is required, presumably the name to give remotely to the uploaded file. Use `basename`?

Comment: I updated my answer with complete version taking care of our exchanges.

Comment: My strong preference is to have `find` execute the script, rather than the script executing `find` — or have two scripts, one that executes the `find` and one that the `find` executes. In context: `find "$picFilesDir" -type f -iname '*.jpg' -exec …` where the `…` can be `bash -c "commands to be executed" arg0 {} +` (where the `{}` and `+` are `find` notation and the commands to be executed use variables from the launching script or whatever is necessary; or the `…` can be `sh script.sh {} +` and `script.sh` is a script that does whatever is necessary. This handles spaces etc in file names.

Comment: Yes, it is an interesting approach :)  still being careful to not multiplicate the scripts.